# How to use form builder to add attribute to form helpers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a form builder in Rails that adds a `disabled` attribute to `text_field` and `select` helpers. This is the simplified version of my code:

```
class LabelFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder  
  %w[text_field select].each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) do |name, *args|
      super(name, :disabled => true, *args)
    end  
  end
end
```

With `text_fields` the attribute gets added properly but with `selects` things get a bit trickier and I keep getting `undefined method merge for #<Array:0x10b5229a0>` errors.

This is my view code (again simplified):

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>      # works!

<%= f.label :person %>
<%= f.select(:person_id, current_user.person_names, :prompt => 'Please select...') %>  # does not work!
```

How can I get line 4 of my class above to work on `select` helpers as well?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

`select` for `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` is defined **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L765)** with the following method signature

```
def select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

`text_field` for `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` is defined *(dynamically)* **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1204)** with the following method signature

```
def text_field(method, options = {})
```

This is one problem; you're code is passing `{ disabled: true }` as the `choices` parameter which is not what Rails is expecting.

The other issue I see relates to my confusion with your intention for

```
super(name, :disabled => true, *args)
```

because you're making `options` in the overloaded method explicitly `{ disabled: true }`, ignoring any options passed in from your view.

I think it's simplest to overload each method independently.

```
class LabelFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder  
  def text_field(method, options={})
    options.reverse_merge! disabled: true
    super(method, options)
  end

  def select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
    html_options.reverse_merge! disabled: true
    super(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
  end
end
```

Notice the use of `reverse_merge!`. This is a Rails method on `Hash` that allows you to provide default values for hash items *(such as for default options as done above)*. This allows other options to be passed to the method you're overloading while providing a sensible default for `:disabled` but still allowing it to be overriden on a case by case basis *(you'd directly pass `disabled: false` to the `select` or `text_field` call)*.

This is untested but should get you close to what you're after.

Comment: Hello and thanks for putting me on the right track here! Your text_field method works and really saved me a lot of work. Your select method, however, doesn't work yet and I am currently trying to find out why. It simply won't add the `disabled` attribute to the `select` element and won't throw an error either...